# What is the meaning of "would" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across the following sentence

> The summers spent at Talland **would end up being** the inspiration for Woolf’s novel To The Lighthouse, and life, it seemed, was pretty blissful.

What's the meaning of “would” in that sentence?

Could it also be written this way without losing its meaning?

> The summers spent at Talland **ended up being** the inspiration for Woolf’s novel To The Lighthouse, and life, it seemed, was pretty blissful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could rewrite it that way.

Here, *would* functions as the past of *will*, which (as I'm sure you know) often has a future meaning.

So here it is a sort of "future in the past". By using it, the writer is choosing to set the "story time" to the period when Woolf was visiting Talland, and looking forward from then to the time when she wrote the novel.

Your formulation with a simple past is a neutral way of writing it, appropriate for academic writing. The form with *would* is more of a story-teller's form of expression, inviting the reader to imagine themselves back in that time.

Comment: To me, the rewritten version sounds slightly "off", perhaps because there's a slight clash of tenses.  "Life **was** pretty blissful", but the being an inspiration hadn't happened yet, so also putting it in the simple past sounds weird.

Comment: @stangdon: you're right. I wasn't taking the whole sentence into consideration in my answer, just the first part.